# Knockoutjs viewmodel data binding not working in dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have created div and load that div when user click on a given link. After div loads, I am clearing node and then applying bindings.

But the data not binding to the view and it also does not generate any error. Please check the below code and suggest any solution:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".popup-list", function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX, y = e.pageY, elm = this,
    left = $(elm).offset().left + 5,
    top = $(elm).offset().top + 25;var d = $("<div/>").addClass('myClass');
    var url = $(this).data("url") || $(this).attr("dataurl");
    d.load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "<h2>Sorry!  Website encounter a problem. Please contact your system administration</h2> <br/>";
            d.html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    }).appendTo('div.myBody').css({ // d.html(tm)
        top: top,
        left: left,
        height: 0, opacity: 0,
    })

    $(d).animate({ height: '346px', width: '1074px', opacity: 1 }, 800)
    ViewModel.getItemList();
    ViewModel.ItemList.extend({ paging: 10 })
    ko.cleanNode($('.myClass'));
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $('.myClass')[0]);
});
```

This is the view model:

```
var ViewModel = {
ItemList: ko.observableArray([]),
getItemList: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl"',
        data: "my para",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            ViewModel.ItemList(data);
        }
    });
}
```

};

This is the partial view:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach : ItemList.currentPageData" >
<li>
    <div >
        <span data-bind="text:myProperty"></span>
    </div>

</li>
```

Comment: what is subList in ViewModel.subList(data)?

Comment: it my mistake subList neet to change as ItemList

Comment: `ko.cleanNode($('.myClass'));` should be `ko.cleanNode($('.myClass')[0]);`

Comment: @haim770 changed still not working

Comment: @Wella, I didn't think it would solve the problem and that's why I didn't post an answer. However, you need to show what your Ajax request is returning (the structure of your `ItemList` array).

Comment: @haim770 here data is object array. object has myProperty

Comment: You should use `ko.applyBindingsToNode` instead if you're only rebinding one node. But you're mixing view and model (you create your view in the model), which is exactly what Knockout tries to dissuade you of. For linking HTML markup and JS logic, you should encapsulate within a *custom binding*. As most cases with Knockout, a working rule is: **if it's not working, I'm probably doing it wrong**. Perhaps you should also explain what you want to *achieve* (eg a notification service).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not creating an "instance" of ViewModel?

Try this:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.getItemList();
viewModel.ItemList.extend({ paging: 10 })
// ko.cleanNode($('.myClass'));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('.myClass')[0]);
```

I commented ko.cleanNode because it does not make sense for me, but you can try either way :)

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: OP is using `object literal` way of contructing VM (not as function) so there is no need of instance to be created . cheers